# 503 Service Unavailable: Invalid webhook response status?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform, webhooks

I have a Parse.com webhook set to call my `new_transaction` method in my Rails application:

```
def new_transaction
  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    :customer_id => params[:customer_id],
    :amount => params[:amount],
    :options => {
      :submit_for_settlement => false
    }
  )

  if result.success?
    return render :json => { :success => "The payment was successful!" }
  else
    return render :json => { :error => "Something went wrong." }
end
```

However, when this is ran, I keep getting a response of

```
{
  "code": 143,
  "error": "Invalid webhook response status: 503 Service Unavailable"
}
```

Not sure what exactly this means or why its being called.

Answer (score 0):

503 errors in the HTTP cycle

Any client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) goes through the following cycle when it communicates with the Web server:
(1) Obtain an IP address from the IP name of the site (the site URL without the leading 'http://'). This lookup (conversion of IP name to IP address) is provided by domain name servers (DNSs).
(2) Open an IP socket connection to that IP address.
(3) Write an HTTP data stream through that socket.
(4) Receive an HTTP data stream back from the Web server in response. This data stream contains status codes whose values are determined by the HTTP protocol. Parse this data stream for status codes and other useful information.

This error occurs in the final step above when the client receives an HTTP status code that it recognises as '503'.